# Can I provide an interface to allow another class to let me access its private variables?

Tags: java, reflection, encapsulation, api-design

First, a clarification: By "interface", I mean any point of interaction between components, not necessarily the "abstract type" kind of interface. (Although if I can use such an interface to do this, great.)

I'm writing a class which is designed to be extended. The problem domain is global optimization, so any end-user-programmer who subclasses my class (I'll call them Steve) will be providing their own problem and algorithm to solve it; I just provide the framework (networking, user interface, etc.). Steve's program might require any number of configuration settings; I want my code to be able to get those settings from the user the same way it gets its own settings (be that from a GUI control panel, an XML configuration file, or whatever). Steve should not have to duplicate any of my code, nor should he have to break Java's type safety or encapsulation model.

Ideally, Steve would be able to write something along these lines:

```
public class SteveClass extends MyFrameworkClass {

    @Configurable
    private int foo;

    @Configurable
    private String bar;

    private boolean baz;

    // implementations of my abstract methods, etc.

}
```

`Configurable` is an annotation that I would provide, that indicates that the annotated variable is a configuration setting that I should get from the user. As you can see, I also want Steve to be able to declare other instance variables for his own internal use, that I never touch.

I was going to implement this by including a method in `MyFrameworkClass` that would iterate through `getClass().getDeclaredFields()` and identify the fields that have `Configurable` annotations. It would then writes the user input to those fields. It doesn't have to look exactly like this, with annotations and all, but you get the idea.

The problem with this, of course, is that `foo` and `bar` are private and code in `MyFrameworkClass` can't write to them, even reflectively. It wouldn't help if they were package-private, since Steve's code won't be in the same package as mine, and I'd rather not require him to make them public, or to add any other interface that would allow anyone but me to access the fields.

Is there any way to do what I want, either by fiddling with `SecurityManager` or doing something completely different?

Comment: How about using a Map to store the parameters and a List to store variable names? You can work directly with the Map(iterate and get the parameters OR you can have a List containing the parameter names, and then you get/set those variables in the Map.

Comment: @ManishSharma Type safety. The parameters won't all be the same type, so it'd have to be a Map of Objects that would be typecast every time they were used. This would get unwieldy and isn't a very clean solution.

Comment: Use the `protected` keyword. It allows access for subclasses that aren't in the same package... Well it might work. I don't know what the JVM would think when the superclass tried to use reflections to access a protected field of a subclass.

Comment: @Dunes Unfortunately, `protected` only allows a subclass to inherit (not directly access) a superclass member, which isn't what I need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Class.getDeclaredFields` to get all of the class's declared fields (including non-public ones), and then `Field.setAccessible(true)` to gain access to it.

```
Field foo = HasPrivate.class.getDeclaredField("foo");
foo.setAccessible(true);
SteveClass steve = new SteveClass();
System.out.println(steve); // "0" -- I set up SteveClass.toString() to just print foo
foo.setInt(hp, 1234);
System.out.println(steve); // "1234"
```

But that means you're depending on the SecurityManager to allow you to do that. It does by default, but that may not work for all users. If that's a prohibitive requirement, there are other, less convenient but potentially more robust options (like requiring that the constructor take a Configuration object, which the user can then get values from).

Comment: In principle, I don't have any objection to passing the data through another object. But could I do that in a type-safe manner? It seems like I'd still have the same problem.

Comment: Kinda depends what you mean by type safe. You could have different methods -- `Configuration.getInt("foo")`, `Configuration.getString("bar")` and have those throw exceptions if the configuration wasn't correct. You could also provide an annotated public static method that returns a Map<String,Class<?>> of which field requires which type, which would let you check the inputs more eagerly (but at the cost of risking mismatch between that declaration and the actual `Configuration.getXxx()` method that gets called per field.)

Answer (score 2):

If I was in your position, I'd be trying to find a way to use the Spring framework to do this for me. That would then let users write this:

```
@Component
public class SteveClass {
    @Value("${steve.foo}")
    private int foo;

    @Value("${steve.bar}")
    private String bar;

    private boolean baz;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DaveClass dave;
}
```

All you'd have to do then is to build a context that has those properties available within it; that's pretty trivial. (Spring does poke around behind the security scenes, but it does so in the “correct” way; all you need to do is to ensure that Spring is trusted, and the rest of your code doesn't need nearly the same level of permissions.) Of course, it also gives Steve plenty of other tools to help him build his app, but that's a story for another question.

Comment: Of course, behind the scenes Spring is using the techniques that yshavit mentions. But it makes them _easy_ to use.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Taymon: I should mention that I don't know too much about how it works with GUI configuration; I tend to write server-side software these days, where there's no interactive display…

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Configuration interface

   ```
   interface Configuration
   {
       int foo ( ) ;

       String bar ( ) ;
   }
   ```
2. Use the Configuration interface

   ```
   public class SteveClass extends MyFrameworkClass {
       private Configuration configuration ;

       // implementations of my abstract methods, etc.

   }
   ```

I think this is called delegation.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because I don't specify the configuration variables—whoever extends my class does.